# Implementing pointwise arithmetic with implicit type conversion

Tags: python, functional-programming, operator-overloading, abc, python-3.3

Suppose I have class `Function`, whose instances are callables that take one argument. I defined pointwise arithmetic for these classes in the straightforward way. Here's a simplified version of my code (I actually have more complex behavior in `__init__` and `__call__` but it's irrelevant for this question):

```
class Function:
  '''
  >>> f = Function(lambda x : x**2)
  >>> g = Function(lambda x : x + 4)
  >>> h = f/g
  >>> h(6)
  3.6
  '''
  def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func
  def __call__(self, value):
    return self.func(value)
  def __truediv__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Function):
        return Function(lambda x:self(x)/other(x))
    else:
        return NotImplemented
  # ...
```

I'm stuck when I try to allow implicit type conversions. For example, I want to be able to write:

```
>>> f = Function(lambda x : x ** 2)
>>> g = f+1
>>> g(5)
26
```

In other words, whenever I see a numeric object `v` in an arithmetic expression next to a `Function` instance, I want to convert `v` to `Function(lambda x : v)`.

In addition, I want to achieve similar behavior for some of my user-defined types (again, whenever I see them in the same binary arithmetic expression with a `Function` object).

While I can certainly code this logic with a brute force assortment of regular and reflected binary arithmetic operators, each checking `isinstance(v, numbers.Number)`, and `isinstance(v, MyUserDefinedType)`, I feel there might be a more elegant way.

Also, if there are any other improvements possible with my design, please let me know. (`Function` objects are created rarely, but called very often, so performance is of some interest.)

EDIT:

To address @Eric's comment, I should clarify that I have another user-defined class `Functional`:

```
class Functional:
  '''
  >>> c = [1, 2, 3]
  >>> f = Functional(lambda x : x + 1)
  >>> f(c)
  [2, 3, 4]
  >>> g = Functional(lambda x : x ** 2)
  >>> h = f + g
  >>> h(c)
  [3, 7, 13]
  '''
  def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func
  @staticmethod
  def from_function(self, function):
    return Functional(function.func)
  def __call__(self, container):
    return type(container)(self.func(c) for c in container)
  def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Functional):
      return Functional(lambda x : self.func(x) + other.func(x))
    else:
      return NotImplemented
```

When I see both a `Function` and a `Functional` instance in the same arithmetic expression, I want `Function` to be implicitly converted to `Functional` using `Functional.from_function` method.

So, implicit type conversion hierarchy goes like this:

- Functional
- Function
- anything else

And I'd like to implicitly convert to the highest type in this hierarchy seen in a given arithmetic expression.

Comment: In general, don't you want to convert all non `Function`s to their lambda equivalent?

Comment: @Eric Almost.. I actually have a higher level class, `Functional`, which operates on containers of values (creating a new container with each value processed by a certain function). When `Function` and `Functional` are in the same expression, I want both to be converted to `Functional`. Other than that, you're right. I'll update my question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "brute force".  Can't you write a utility function `funcOrLambda(obj)` that returns `obj` if the argument is a function or an instance of your `Function` class, otherwise returns `lambda x: obj` (or whatever logic you need)?  Then you don't need to repeat the logic in every magic method.

Comment: If `Functional` subclasses `Function`, then operator lookup will happen first on the derived class.

Comment: Have you looked at [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) as a CAS?

Comment: @Eric: yes, I like the subclassing idea - I tried it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this for all operators would work well:

```
def __truediv__(self, other):
  if callable(other):
      return Function(lambda x:self(x)/other(x))
  else:
      return Function(lambda x:self(x)/other)
```

Comment: Thanks, that would seem to work, and it might be a lot faster than the solution I am currently trying out (I'm going to post in a sec). But I'll need to deal with `Functional` separately, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make all the operators in your `Function` class accept arbitrary values, which will be applied to the result of the underlying function if they're not functions themselves. For example, to extend allow `f / 5`, when `f` is a Function, simply modify the `__truediv__` implementation you have to:

```
def __truediv__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Function):
        return Function(lambda x:self(x)/other(x))
    else:
        return Function(lambda x:self(x)/other)
```

You can optionally do some type checking to make sure that's sane (and raise errors early rather than later on), but it works without that.

Comment: Thx.. I'll probably go with the more general approach of checking `if callable` rather than `if isinstance(other, Function)`, since the only reason `Function` isn't an instance of built-in `function` is that I am not allowed to subclass `function`... So all callables look to me equivalent to `Function` instances.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments and the other answers, I tried this approach. I'm posting it to ask for feedback. I like that I can handle both `Function` and `Functional` in one swoop, but I'm afraid it might be very expensive in terms of performance:

```
class Function:
    '''
    >>> f = Function(lambda x : x**2)
    >>> g = Function(lambda x : x + 4)
    >>> h = f/g
    >>> h(6)
    3.6
    >>> k = f + 1
    >>> k(5)
    26
    >>> m = f + (lambda x : x + 1)
    >>> m(5)
    31
    '''
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if isinstance(arg, Function):
            self.func = arg.func
        elif callable(arg):
            self.func = arg
        else:
            self.func = lambda x : arg
    def __call__(self, value):
        return self.func(value)
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(lambda x:Function(self)(x)/Function(other)(x))
    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(lambda x:Function(other)(x)/Function(self)(x))
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(lambda x:Function(self)(x)+Function(other)(x))
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(lambda x:Function(other)(x)+Function(self)(x))
    # ...


class Functional(Function):
    '''
    >>> c = [1, 2, 3]
    >>> f = Functional(lambda x : x + 1)
    >>> f(c)
    [2, 3, 4]
    >>> g = Functional(lambda x : x ** 2)
    >>> h = f + g
    >>> h(c)
    [3, 7, 13]
    '''
    def __call__(self, container):
        return type(container)(self.func(c) for c in container)
```